# Chern number of positive spinor bundle

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, vector-bundles, 4-manifolds, spin-geometry, chern-classes

What is the second chern number $c_2(V_+)$ of the positive spinor bundle on a 4-manifold, in particular $S^4$? Why is it that $V_+$ is the same as the quaternion line-bundle?

Thanks,